# Automatically click blocked ads in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I understand that blocking ads via the uBlock extension for Google Chrome. takes away revenue from the site. So, I'd like to automatically click all the ads but not see them or the pages they go to. That way, I do not have to see them but the websites still can make the money from them.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's hard to say where this sits ethically. If you don't show the ads, the site makes no money, but the subject of the advert doesn't lose any. If you do click them, the site makes more money than just showing the ad (in most cases), but the subject of the advert pays more and never actually got any chance of there being a sale.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider about your hypothetical extension.

1. uBlock is designed to fully block the domain which the ad is coming from so the ad is never loaded into your browser at at all. This is why using any AdBlocker will always boost your browsing speeds. I appreciate this feature because there are plenty of sites which get over 25% of their connections blocked because they are ad or tracking related. The extension which you are imagining would have to read uBlock's blocked domains list, visit those URLs in the background or render the ads in the background and simulate a click.
2. I am 99.995% positive that ad companies keep track of the click-rate of ads to make sure some blogger isn't spamming clicks on their own site to generate revenue for themselves. Auto-clicking on every single ad on a site could set off red flags and actually hurt the website(s) which you were trying to help.

Comment: I wouldn't want it to spam click the ads. I would want it set so every time I visited a page on which there was a blocked ad, that particular ad would be clicked one time.  Ideally the ad'cling could occur once a day.  Maybe it could be customizable to click all ads or just the ones I select.

Comment: @Wozzie It sounds like you have a great idea for a Chrome extension, this is a very good chance to learn some programming :)